# get sum of column and without sum column in linq query

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

```cs
m.Items
    .GroupBy(x => x.AgeRangeCode)
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        population = g.Sum(x => x.population), 
        ageRangeCode = x.ageRange
    });
```

i wrote the same query but it is not working.

i want to get sum of population column grouped by agerange and also want other column data without sum.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean *other column data without sum*? The original data from Items before group?

Comment: means also want sum of population and also age range, as you can see in query

Comment: Hmmm, not understand your question, your above code did the sum and age range. But anyway, you should grab the grouped key for AgeRangeCode like this: `ageRangeCode = x.Key`. Your current query will get a compilation error on `ageRangeCode` part.

Comment: well it worked can you tell me how can i get join table columns also

Comment: .Join(_kcdbContext.ReachAgeRanges,
o => o.AgeRangeCode,
p => p.AgeRangeCode,
(o,p)=>
 new {
 connectedpop = o.ProjectedPopulation,
 p.AgeRangeCode,p.Description
 } )
 .GroupBy(x => x.AgeRangeCode)
 .Select(g => new
 {
                                          connectedpop = g.Sum(x => x.connectedpop),
                                          ageRangeCode = g.Key
                                      })
                                      .ToList();

Comment: Well, that is what I ask in the first comment  To get the set of data for the group, you can work with `.ToList()`. It should be: `.Join(...).GroupBy(x => x.AgeRangeCode) .Select(g => new { connectedpop = g.Sum(x => x.connectedpop), ageRangeCode = g.Key, Data = g.ToList() }) .ToList();`. The `Data` property will be `IEnumerable` of anonymous type based on the result returned from `.Join`. Is this what you want?

Comment: yes i want same but it is giving error 
.ToList()' could not be translated.

Comment: no success actually in data i need object given by join on the basis of age range code

Comment: Hi, you want to get the sum value for `population` and other column without sum, how is your model design which is related to this linq? What do you mean `but it is not working`, what's the error message?